# Adapt the target of a shortcut

Tags: c#, .net, windows, directory, exe

I have created a software, the exe file and the dependencies are in the folder named Debug.

To execute the program the user have to click on the exe file named "start". The exe file is in the Debug folder.

I have created a shortcut and put the shortcut at the root of "My Software Folder".

I want that it works for all the persons I send the folder "My Software Folder".
The problem is that the Target of the shortcut is made for my computer.

"C:\Users\MYNAME\My Software Folder\Debug"

I want to change it to :

"\Debug"

but it dosen't work, the answer I get is : 
"The name '\Debug" specified in the Target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file name are correct."

Comment: make a batch script `start Debug\start.exe`

Comment: The slash at the start makes the path absolute from the root of current drive, to make it relative to the current folder omit the slash.

Answer (score 0):

"make a batch script start Debug\start.exe – Joe DF"

This solution works.

I have created a batch file with the following code :

@echo Start

cd "Debug\"

start "" "UpdateMyDb.exe"